# App development for both smartphone and website?

Tags: frameworks, cross-platform, mobile-phones, titanium, rhodes

I've been looking at mobile development frameworks including Rhodes, Titanium, and PhoneGap.  As a large part of the application we're developing will also be integrated on the web (a game), we'd love to re-use code so as to not reinvent the wheel.  Is there a best way to accomplish this?  Is there a framework out there with which you can develop for more than just smartphone devices?  I thought I remembered seeing one, but can't for the live of me remember what it was.

Thanks,
- Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Titanium is fairly cross-platform and extends beyond mobile phone development:

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-cross-platform-application-development/

Answer (score 1):

As I know, Titanium (Mobile) is currently supported for iOS (iPhone / iPad), Android and Blackberry platform using Javascript langauge. For Titanium Desktop version, you can write your apps for Window /Mac / Linux OS using Javascript / Ruby and Python language.

My company is using Titanium Mobile to develop app for Android / iPhone and I feel happy about Titanium. It's so easy to write app.

Answer (score 0):

Rhodes will perform builds for Win32 as well as all smartphones.   There are some Rhodes developers who share code between Rhodes and Ruby and Rails to deliver a website as well.  We would hope however that if there is a device that you wanted to target with the mobile website that you would build a NATIVE app with Rhodes versus a mobile website.